# React.js "TypeError: Cannot set property 'setState' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, es6-class, setstate

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Comment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editing: false,
    };
  }

  edit() {
    this.setState = { editing: true };
  }

  remove() {
    this.props.deleteFromBoard(this.props.index);
  }

  save() {
    this.props.updateCommentText(this.refs.newText.value, this.props.index);
    this.setState = { editing: false }
  }

  renderNormal() {
    return (
      <div className="commentContainer">
        <div className="commentText>">{this.props.children}</div>
        <button onClick={this.edit} className="button-primary">Edit
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.remove} className="button-danger">Remove
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderForm() {
    return (
      <div className="commentContainer">
        <textarea ref="newText" defaultValue={this.props.children}>
    </textarea>
        <button onClick={this.save} className="button-success">Save
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.editing)
      return this.renderForm;
    else
      return this.renderNormal;
  }
}

export default Comment;
```

When I am trying to execute this code it says that "**Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.**" I have also tried enclosing the return statement inside a div but it still gives the same error. I am new to React.js, so can someone point to some documentation or explain the reason behind this error and how to solve it? I have also looked at similar questions but couldn't find something which matches my requirements.

EDIT: I have edited my render to look like this

```
render() {
if(this.state.editing)
  return this.renderForm();
else
  return this.renderNormal();
}
```

which has solved that issue but now when I click on Edit it gives the following error:

**TypeError: Cannot set property 'setState' of undefined**

EDIT: This got solved by making the following changes in the constructor

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
  editing : false,
};
this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);
this.save = this.save.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

correction :

1. You are missing  function   call.
2. **if else** not used in correct way.Instead you can use ternary operator.

   `render() {
     {
       this.state.editing
         ? this.renderForm()
         : this.renderNormal()
     }
   }`

OR using **if - else**.

```
render() {

  let MyComp = "";
  if (this.state.editing) 
    MyComp = this.renderForm;
  else 
    MyComp = this.renderNormal;
  }

    return (<MyComp/>);
}
```

3. In `edit` and `save` function you are using `this`.but you didn't binding `this` to component scope.

Do `this` binding Either  :

in constructor :

```
constructor(){

   this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);
   this.save = this.save.bind(this);
}
```

Or using arrow function:

```
edit = () = {
  //code
}

save = () => {

  //code
}
```

Comment: Rectifed. Thanks.
Now it gives the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: @GVSandeep check point 3,u need to bind this to component scope